# Unable to fetch dynamic queryParams without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to add `queryParams` dynamically to url without reloading page.  So I carried out using the `Location` service as below,

```
this.location.go(`${path}?tab=xxx`); // works perfectly without page reload
```

Now the problem is when I try to access the `queryParams` it returns empty.

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((qp) => {
      console.log('updated queryParams', qp); // returns {}
    });
```

whereas when the same code works if the page is reloaded properly.  Any way to the same without refreshing the page in angular or should I try with native js?

Comment: Not sure of your issue, seems to worke [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d6nury?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @temp_user the above code update the url with queryParams but when i try to get it via `this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe` it returns {}

Comment: You can clearly see that it gets updated in real time though

Comment: updating the url is not my problem; retrieving back is not working.

Comment: means `location` service doesn't listen the `activatedRoute.QueryParams`.  whereas  `this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { 'tab': 'xxx' }});` listens to the subscribe method as well as doesn't reload the page. Thanks @AndreiTătar for pointing out the question.